# organizar formulario flutter

Tags: formularios, flutter, text

Necesito como poner 2 TextFormField uno al lado del otro ejemplo:

_***dato***    ****dato****

mi código es el siguiente

```
body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Nombre(s)",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left, validator: (text) {
                  if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Campo vacio';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Apellidos",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left, validator: (text) {
                  if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Campo vacio';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15,),
```

Comment: Usa un row. Revisa el código, ponle formato, así es imposible de leer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner dos TextFormField uno al lado del otro, puedes usar una fila (Row) y añadir cada TextFormField como un hijo de la fila:

```
  Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Nombre(s)",
            border: OutlineInputBorder()
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        validator: (text) {
          if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
            return 'Campo vacio';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(width: 15),
    Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Apellidos",
            border: OutlineInputBorder()
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        validator: (text) {
          if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
            return 'Campo vacio';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

También puedes ajustar el tamaño de cada TextFormField usando el widget Expanded, que ocupará todo el espacio disponible en la fila. En este caso, también he añadido un SizedBox con un ancho de 15 entre ambos TextFormField para añadir un poco de espacio entre ellos.

Comment: Estimado, ¿has probado el código?

Comment: Muy bueno, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `Row` para poder poner Widgets uno al lado del otro, también nos ayudaremos de un `Expanded` para que el Widget ocupe el espacio necesario, el `Expanded` tiene una propiedad que es `flex`, este te ayudará para que puedas ver que Widget quieres que ocupe más espacio, pondremos 1 y 1 en cada uno para que esté equilibrado:

```
    body: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: TextFormField(
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Nombre(s)", border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              validator: (text) {
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Campo vacio';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: TextFormField(
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Apellidos", border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              validator: (text) {
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Campo vacio';
                }
                 return null;
               },
              ),
             ),
            ],
           ),
          const SizedBox(
           height: 15,
         )
       ]);
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Muy útil, gracias por su ayuda